# How to infer correctly keys of generic T extends X within class methods?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a model `FileInfo` and I have a generic class handling the File model:

```js
class FileInfo {
    size: number = 0;

    constructor(
        public readonly path: string
    ) {}
}

class FileSystem<T extends FileInfo> {
    public find(query: Partial<T>) {
        //do something
    }

    public findByPath(path: string) {
        // TS2345: Argument of type '{ path: string; }' is not
        // assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<T>'.
        return this.find({path: path});
    }
}

const filesystem = new FileSystem();
filesystem.findByPath('text.txt');
```

As you can see, I get a TS2345 error, although TS has every information necessary about T, in this case all properties.

When I change `public find(query: Partial<T>)` to `public find(query: Partial<FileInfo>)` everything compiles, but that's not my goal.

When I try `keyof T` vs `keyof File` within Filesystem::find I clearly see that Typescript returns not all information for the first one.

My questions: Is this a bug (I doubt that) or what do I miss here?
And additional question: What technique do I miss to make this work?

Would love to get some links with more information from you.

I use Typescript 3.3.3333.

[Playground link](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiCWICmBJAdgMwPbQN4ChojoJ4AvJALmjQFcBbAIyQCdoBeaABgG59DiwLGggAXFrWCisLABQDixAA61GIeMGgskYACbCQAT2hKwogBbUxLeGgDmC6AEo8AX3zv8oSDATIAyoZiSPQAPAAq0EgAHqJIaLq+iKiYWAB8eI4qahrQGLa6sgCOtKyG1AAKYCyi8GAgEWkuBIqKAPRt+iRY9EgWtg6KnorZ6pr5CQBChlUWsqYWVuIDzY7tbdDh-gBMAMwALACs1ACCLHYM8aLQWBjQooZKSNAA5LgmZpYky-Y80K4vaDwGBoLCiNbEDrQHzwOxoMBqZ7SD4sMC9OJsW73R7PF5VGp1BrhNIvAB0EKI2lEtBYaHu5mBpImhVwCy+bNcTj4Qw8-CEImu+WQECCcXoHBoSAA7nBkoFgvRZFz8EKkCKFUyCtNZuZZC84rFSaJYi9lar1WLNQlZKzPtR9TFREaTZy-h0pTIANYwaxgexIIxAA)

Comment: When I try this in the playground, I see your error and also "*Duplicate identifier 'File'.*" because `File` is a built-in interface. If I rename `File` to `FileInfo` or any other non-conflicting name, both errors go away.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I changed the code slightly to not use File as class name and moved the inferred Partial<T> call inside the class, so we get the error message again.

Comment: I see what you mean. There seems to be something strange going on with the variance of `Partial<T>`. You can reproduce this behavior with a single lambda: `const f = <T extends { a: any }>(a: T["a"]): Partial<T> => ({ a })`.

Comment: I guess it's related to https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29952